# How to do regex validation in PrimeNg table editor?

Tags: angular, primeng-datatable

I am using PrimeNG DataTable editor. I want to implement validation with Regex for each field.

Regex Validation: only number and only alphabets.

How can this be done?

Comment: can you provide your code or ui?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using (keyup) or (onBlur) event.

**In your component.html file**

```
<p-table [value]="cars">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Motor</th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData>
        <tr>
            <td pEditableColumn>
                <p-cellEditor>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                        <input pInputText type="text" [(ngModel)]="rowData.name" (keyup)="onKey(rowData.name)">
                    </ng-template>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                        {{rowData.name}}
                    </ng-template>
                </p-cellEditor>
            </td>
            <td pEditableColumn>
                <p-cellEditor>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                        <input pInputText type="text" [(ngModel)]="rowData.motor" required>
                    </ng-template>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                        {{rowData.motor}}
                    </ng-template>
                </p-cellEditor>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

**In component.ts file**

```
public cars: any[];
public letters = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/;
  constructor(){
    this.cars = [];
    this.cars.push({name: 'Audi', motor: '100ch'});
    this.cars.push({name: 'Honda', motor: '200ch'});
    this.cars.push({name: 'Mercedes', motor: '100ch'});
    this.cars.push({name: 'Renault', motor: '100ch'});
    this.cars.push({name: 'VW', motor: '100ch'});
  }
onKey(event:any){
    if(!event.match(this.letters))
    {
     console.log('Please input alphanumeric characters only');
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is there any way to prevent one from entering input other than alphanumeric in the above case ?

Comment: @learner1 just return false in side the method `if(!event.match(this.letters))
    {
     return false;
    }`